# How do I take two integer values from a string then put them back into two separate integers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a double dimension string array that holds each buttons specific coordinates

```
string[,] gridPass = new string[20, 20];


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (int row in Enumerable.Range(0, 20))
        {
            foreach (int col in Enumerable.Range(0, 20))
            {

                Button b = new Button();
                b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
                b.Location = new Point(row * 30, col * 30);
                gridPass[row, col] = row.ToString() + " - " + col.ToString();
                b.Tag =  gridPass[row, col];
                b.Text = gridPass[row, col];
                this.Controls.Add(b);
                b.Click += new EventHandler(AttackHandler);
            }


        }
```

When I attack using the event handler on my buttons

```
private void AttackHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton;
            string tagValue = "";

            clickedButton = (Button)sender;
            tagValue = (string)clickedButton.Tag;
            theSea.attackLocation(tagValue);

        }
```

It's obviously sending a string like 0 - 1 or 8 - 4 whatever the button's coordinates are.
When I pass that string to the attackLocation method in my Sea class I want to be able to extract those two numbers to reference them with the array in my Sea class to see if there is a boat there. I Need those X and Y values back to reference the exact same location in another array basically. So I can do something like.

```
public void attackLocation(string attackCoords)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Attacking " + attackCoords);
        x = however to convert it back;
        y = however to convert it back;
        foreach (Ship s in shipList)
        {
            if (grid[x,y] == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Attacked this block before."); 
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to extract the hyphen separated values and apply [String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) on them to remove the spaces before we pass it to [int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) to convert string to number.

```
//b.Tag =  "0 - 1";    
string []arr = b.Tag.ToString().Split('-');    
int num1 = int.Parse(arr[0].Trim());
int num2 = int.Parse(arr[1].Trim());
```

Comment: now I remember using that for something similiar a last semester I think that's exactly what I need I'm going to try it as soon as I go get my girlfriend from work :( Thanks!

Comment: everything looks like it's going to work right but one thing I have read scribble under trim

Comment: private void AttackHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton;
            string tagValue;
            clickedButton = (Button)sender;          
            tagValue = (string)clickedButton.Tag;
            string []arr = clickedButton.Tag.Split('-');
            int x = int.Parse(arr[0].Trim());
            int y = int.Parse(arr[2].Trim());
            theSea.attackLocation(x,y);

        }

Comment: scribble under Split('-');     says object does not contain a definition for split

Comment: I think you need to use ToString over b.Tag

Answer (score 3):

Create a class to hold the row and column values and set the `Tag` to that object. Then you won't need to do string conversions.

```
class SeaPoint
{
  public int Row { get; set; }
  public int Column { get; set; }
}
```

In Load:

```
        foreach (int col in Enumerable.Range(0, 20))
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            b.Location = new Point(row * 30, col * 30);
            gridPass[row, col] = row.ToString() + " - " + col.ToString();
            b.Tag =  new SeaPoint() { Row = row, Column = col }; // <---  Changed.
            b.Text = gridPass[row, col];
            this.Controls.Add(b);
            b.Click += new EventHandler(AttackHandler);
        }
```

And AttackHandler:

```
private void AttackHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    var seaPoint = (SeaPoint)clickedButton.Tag; // <-- Changed
    theSea.attackLocation(seaPoint);  // rewrite attackLocation to accept a SeaPoint.
}
```

Comment: You could also just use built-in `Point` , `X` would be Column, `Y` would be Row

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Agreed. Or you could use an `int[]`. The point is that you do not have to be passing strings around and parsing them everywhere.

Comment: I see what your saying this solution is the one I came too that seemed to be working so I was trying it out but then ran into all these problems with the strings. Now my question is since i've passed attackLocation a point the tagvalue of the button how do I make the statement like  if(grid[point] == 1) {MessageBox.Show("Attacked Before");} to check the grid[,] to get information about that location on it

Comment: @dsquaredtech `grid[point.Row, point.Column] == 1`, I would think.

Answer (score 0):

Make this regular expression:

```
new Regex(@"(\d+) - (\d+)")
```

Use the regex's Match on the string you want to extract the numbers from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx

It'll return a Match object, which will contain two groups (assuming I'm remembering the difference between groups and captures right...). The groups' values will be string represenations of the two integers. int.Parse() them.